# Retrieving multiple entries from a MySQL database in VB

Tags: mysql, database, arrays, vb.net

I am building a room booking service for my school computing coursework and I am not totally sure how to go about retrieving previously made bookings from the database. I know how to connect to a database and read one entry but not multiple.

So far I have:

```
   strBookingQuery = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE Date = '" & ConvertedBookingDate & "'"

    Dim Cmd As New MySqlCommand(strBookingQuery, Newconnection)
    Newconnection.ConnectionString = strServerString
    Newconnection.Open()
    reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
    reader.Read()
```

This pulls 5 variables from the database, the date, the period which it is booked, the length of the booking, the UserID and the RoomID in that order, and I wish to write them into integer the last four variables into integer arrays, the array size is 7 as the maximum number of bookings in a day is 7. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Also I apologise for any bad coding, I am an A level student so I haven't really been coding for a very long time.

Something along the lines of this?

```
Function GetBookingData()

    strBookingQuery = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE Date = '" & ConvertedBookingDate & "'"

    Dim Cmd As New MySqlCommand(strBookingQuery, Newconnection)
    Newconnection.ConnectionString = strServerString
    Newconnection.Open()
    reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
    reader.Read()
    For SP = 1 To intBookingCount
        Do While reader.Read()
            StartPeriod(SP) = reader.GetInt16(1)
        Loop
        MsgBox(StartPeriod(SP))
    Next

    Newconnection.Close()

End Function
```

Comment: Each time you call `reader.Read`, it will read the next row into the reader.  The `reader.Read` method will return `False` once you have read all of the rows, so you can just make a loop `While reader.Read`.

Comment: I tried that before and it worked for reading the first array, but the second array was returned as all 0s

Comment: That's difficult to explain without more details.  That should work that way, if you were doing it right.

Comment: So if I were to create a for loop, the same length as the number of entries in the database, for each of the rows and put a do while loop inside each of the different for loops?

Comment: What kind of object are you reading the data into?  Can you show the code that currently reads the data from the current row?  Or better yet, show the code that loops through all the rows which didn't work properly.

Comment: That's the function I'm trying to use at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what it is your are attempting to do, but I suspect that what you actually want is something like this:

```
Function GetBookingData()
    strBookingQuery = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE Date = '" & ConvertedBookingDate & "'"
    Dim Cmd As New MySqlCommand(strBookingQuery, Newconnection)
    Newconnection.ConnectionString = strServerString
    Newconnection.Open()
    reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
    For SP = 1 To intBookingCount
        If Not reader.Read() Then
            Exit For
        End If
        StartPeriod(SP) = reader.GetInt16(1)
        MsgBox(StartPeriod(SP))
    Next
    Newconnection.Close()    
End Function
```

However, there are some further recommendations that I would make.  First, you should add a `Using` block, when possible, for each `IDisposable` object that you use (e.g. Newconnection, Cmd).  The `Using` block is safer because if execution leaves the block for any reason (e.g. an exception), it will still properly dispose of the object for you.

Second, you should use parameters in your command rather than appending the date value directly into your `strBookingQuery` string.  When you append the value into the SQL string yourself like that, you open your database to SQL-injection attacks.  Also, specifically with dates, you could run into culture differences too (e.g. MM-dd-yyyy vs. dd-MM-yyyy).

Thirdly, it would be easier to use a collection of some sort, such as `List(Of Integer)` to store the values that are read from the database, rather than into an array.  It's not great to assume that the number of rows will always be the same fixed size, and it's inconvenient to use arrays when dealing with lists of variable length.  Collections are made precisely for that kind of thing.  Rather than keeping track of the fixed length and the current index in the  array,with a collection you can simply call the `Add` method when you need to add a new item.

So, my recommendation would be to do it more like this:

```
Public Function GetBookingData(bookingDate As Date) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim data As New List(Of Integer)()
    Using connection As New MySqlConnection()
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString
        connection.Open()
        Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE Date = @BookingDate"
        Using command As New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
            Dim parameter As IDbDataParameter = command.CreateParameter()
            parameter.ParameterName = "@BookingDate"
            parameter.Value = bookingDate
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter)                
            Using reader As DbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                Do While reader.Read()
                    data.Add(reader.GetInt16(1))
                Loop
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    Return data
End Function
```